# how do I write the positions to a file

Tags: python

The full task that I have been assigned from school is:

Develop a program that identifies individual words in a sentence, stores these in a list and replaces each word in the original sentence with the position of that word in the list.

For example, the sentence

```
ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY
```

Contains the words `ASK, NOT, WHAT, YOUR, COUNTRY, CAN, DO, FOR, YOU` The sentence can be recreated from the positions of these words in this list using the sequence

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,3,9,6,7,8,4,5
```

Save the list of words and the positions of these words in the sentence as separate files or as a single file.

Analyse the requirements for this system and design, develop, test and evaluate a program to:

identify the individual words in a sentence and store them in a list
create a list of positions for words in that list
save these lists as a single file or as separate files.

Here is my current code:

```
sentencelist=[] #variable list for the sentences
word=[] #variable list for the words
positionofword=[]
words= open("words.txt","w")
position= open("position.txt","w")

question=input("Do you want to enter a sentence? Answers are Y or N.").upper()
if question=="Y":
    sentence=input("Please enter a sentance").upper() #sets to uppercase so it's easier to read
    sentencetext=sentence.isalpha or sentence.isspace()
    while sentencetext==False: #if letters have not been entered
        print("Only letters are allowed") #error message
        sentence=input("Please enter a sentence").upper() #asks the question again
        sentencetext=sentence.isalpha #checks if letters have been entered this time

elif question=="N":
    print("The program will now close")

else:
    print("please enter a letter")


sentence_word = sentence.split(' ')
for (i, check) in enumerate(word): #orders the words
    print(sentence)

sentence_words = sentence.split(' ')
for (i, check) in enumerate(sentence_words): #orders the words
    if (check == word):
        positionofwords=print(i+1)
        break

else:
    print("This didn't work")

words.write(str(sentence_words) + " ")
position.write(str(positionofwords) + " ")

words.close()
position.close()
```

This doesn't work. The error I get is:

```
NameError: name 'positionofwords' is not defined
```

What I would like to know is why `positionofwords=print(i+1)` does not work in this case and what I would do instead.

Comment: That statement is in a `for` loop in an `if` check. If that `for` loop is iterating through an empty iterator, or if none of the items matches, that variable won't be assigned. Even if that did work, though, `print` always returns None. Maybe you mean `positionofwords = i + 1; print(positionofwords)`.

Comment: To add to zondo's comment, you are attempting an operation on 'positionof words' but initialized 'positionofword' as an empty list - note the 's' in the end.

Comment: zondo thank you. so where i have 'positionofwords=print(i+1)' i've put what you suggested, i also took out the if==check line. but i have the word folder working. just the position folder has '1' in it.

Comment: postoronnim you've sort of lost me, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = 'ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY'
>>> words = s.split()
>>> for w in words:
        print(words.index(w) + 1)
```

Output:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
1
3
9
6
7
8
4
5

Comment: Afaq i would like the sentence to be inputted by the user and then the positions read to a file.